# Is there a French equivalent for "long pig"?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

In English, *long pig* is [human flesh eaten by cannibals](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long-pig?showCookiePolicy=true). As I couldn't find a French equivalent for it in any of the dictionaries that I can look up into, I was wondering if anyone knows a good French translation for this imaginative expression.

Comment: This is an interesting question, indoxica.  I have never heard of this expression and neither has my girlfriend, and we are both anglophones.  I really enjoy questions like this, because they are educating in both languages.  It's always interesting to see if an expression or equivalent can be found!

Comment: @Patrick Sebastien Indeed, they are. I do appreciate... your appreciation of my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Pig is a culinary term that refers to human beings.
The most accurate translation would be "Chair humaine".

You could also use "Bidoche" or "Barbaque" if you want slang words about "Viande" (aka meat).

There are lots of expressions about [Viande](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viande) on [cntrl.fr](http://www.cnrtl.fr), but nothing about cannibalism.

From wikipedia about [Cannibalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism#Early_modern_era):

> The friar Diego de Landa reported about Yucatán instances,[[67]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism#cite_note-67)and
>   there have been similar reports by Purchas from Popayán, Colombia, and
>   from the Marquesas Islands of Polynesia, where human flesh was called
>   long pig[[68]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism#cite_note-68).

Comment: _Bidoche_: I like the sound of it. That's why I've just upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no French equivalent that I could find.

All there is, is the original Marquesaan (Polynesian) word "puaa ao" which can be translated into English as "long pig that speaks".
You could translate that literally : "Le grand porc / cochon qui parle".

Comment: I would definitely use “porc”, as it more readily relates to meat.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a similar expression. To convey meaning, my best guess would be to translate it simply by “chair humaine” (literally “human flesh”). If you want to preserve style, I can think of anything better than @Kwaio.